# Wrong second count for blackdetect filter in ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I issue this command on a 8 minutes 20 seconds video in order to detect blackframes.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hts# ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=test.ts,blackdetect[out0]" -show_entries tags=lavfi.black_start,lavfi.black_end -of default=nw=1
```

I am expecting to get proper seconds back from ffprobe indicating where the blackframes are.

Instead I receive very very high numbers.

I need to mention that I cut this video from the end of a larger stream using tail. The stream is configured to add a keyframe every 0.5 seconds. Could this be the reason? And how could I cope with this?

```
ffprobe version git-2016-03-31-54ccaae Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 33.100 / 57. 33.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3222100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3222100] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3222100] no frame!
Input #0, lavfi, from 'movie=test.ts,blackdetect[out0]':
  Duration: N/A, start: 78576.400000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x256 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78681.9
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78682
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78720.5
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78721.1
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78761.4
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78762.6
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78770.9
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78771
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78781
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78781.2
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78801.2
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78801.4
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78821.4
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78821.5
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78851.5
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78851.7
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78871.7
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78871.8
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78891.8
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78892
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78919
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78919.2
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78949.2
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78949.3
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78979.3
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78979.5
TAG:lavfi.black_start=78999.5
TAG:lavfi.black_end=78999.6
TAG:lavfi.black_start=79022.6
TAG:lavfi.black_end=79022.8
TAG:lavfi.black_start=79042.8
TAG:lavfi.black_end=79043
TAG:lavfi.black_start=79063
TAG:lavfi.black_end=79063.1
[h264 @ 0x3260360] concealing 284 DC, 284 AC, 284 MV errors in P frame
```

Comment: Just checking to see that  you know that the startpts time of the stream is `78576.4`, so the first blackframe detected at `78681.9` is 1m45s into the video . Is that too high?

Comment: Thats exactly it. I realised that too. Using the start time from the first pts timestamp is the corrective factor to fix the timestamps.